# Antlr3 with C++ target: invalid conversion from const CommonTokenType*

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to get a super-simple grammar working for ANTLR3 with a C++ target.

I'm finding that if I refer to any variables in my action, I get the following error:

> `invalid conversion from ‘const CommonTokenType* {aka const CommonToken<Traits<NlpCfgRuleAntlrLexer, NlpCfgRuleAntlrParser>>*}’ to ‘Traits<NlpCfgRuleAntlrLexer, NlpCfgRuleAntlrParser>::CommonTokenType* {aka CommonToken<Traits<NlpCfgRuleAntlrLexer, NlpCfgRuleAntlrParser>>*}’ [-fpermissive]`

Here's the core part of my grammar:

```
def 
    : ID ':' {$ID.text;}
    ;
ID  : 'a'..'z'+ ;
```

If I go into the generated C++ source to this line:

```
ImplTraits::CommonTokenType* ID1 = NULL;
```

... and change it to:

```
const ImplTraits::CommonTokenType* ID1 = NULL;
```

... then the compile error goes away.

Perhaps the fix is here: (?)

https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3/commit/0c90ab8f8506a46e37f54988207cb4d6a1d2596a

If so, might I ask why super-super-super basic functionality is broken in ANTLR's C++ target?

If it's helpful to anyone else, I'm currently working around this by running a command in my Makefile to manually search and replace in the generated code:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/    ImplTraits::CommonTokenType\*/    const ImplTraits::CommonTokenType*/g' $(GEN)/mydir/*.cpp
```

Comment: Look at mine pull request, is fixes much more.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/pull/145 is also fixes some performance problems. Without these fixes are C a C++ targets much slower that Java one.